# Variable arguments in a Macro

Tags: c, macros, visual-c++, variadic-functions

I have a function which takes variable arguments, something like the following

```
int log_data (LOG_TYPE eType, ...)
{
    /** some logging related stuff here **/
}
```

In the header file, I use something like

```
#ifdef LOGGING_ENABLED
int log_data (int nType, ...);
#else
#define log_data(_x_, ...)
#endif
```

Basically, the idea is to SWITCH debugging ON & OFF ~~~

- Problem:
  The above logic works perfectly fine in Linux & gcc, but errors outs during compilation in Windows VC++.

Answer (score 4):

Variadic macros are relatively new, for example: [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415%28VS.80%29.aspx) says that "Support for variadic macros was introduced in Visual C++ 2005."  You might have an older version.

*Edit*: you are declaring `log_data` if you want debugging, and not if you don't.  This means that you have the *definition* of the function in an `#ifdef` as well.  As long as you're doing this, a solution would be:

```
int log_data (int nType, ...)
{
#ifdef LOGGING_ENABLED
     /* the code to do logging */
#else
     return 0; /* or whatever */
#endif
}
```

and in your header file, declare the function as usual:

```
int log_data (int nType, ...);
```

This has a disadvantage that the function call exists even when you're not logging, but the advantage is that it will work without preprocessor support for varargs.

Comment: That "disadvantage" should be optimized away by any reasonably modern compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Older versions of VC++ do not support variable arguments in macros.

You can use this trick to get around it:

```
#ifdef LOGGING_ENABLED
#define log_data log_data_impl
#else
#define log_data
#endif

// usage:
log_data(level, ...)
```

UPDATE - Another possible workaround:

```
#ifdef LOGGING_ENABLED
#define log_data(P) log_data_impl P // no braces around P!
#else
#define log_data(P)
#endif

// usage: we have to use two braces
log_data((level, ...));
```

Comment: To say the statement "VC++ doesn't support..." is ambiguous. For example, it *does* support it on later versions.

Comment: You could just say `#ifdef LOGGING_DISABLED #define log_data #endif` and then all calls to `log_data(x, y, z)` would be transformed to `(x, y, z)` and be evaluated in void context, but this wouldn't work if the arguments have side effects (which they probably shouldn't, just for the record).